# Is it possible to create a new CosmosDB account using @azure/cosmos sdk?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli, azure-sdk

Pretty sure this is a trivial question but couldn`t find any clue on the [`@azure/cosmos`](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/javascript/azure-cosmos/3.3.6/index.html) package documentation. 
I'm searching for something like we have in Azure CLI, this is a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/scripts/cli/sql/create?toc=%2fcli%2fazure%2ftoc.json), but in `@azure/cosmos` package. More help of what I want in `az cosmosdb create` command [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cosmosdb-create).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pointing to the Cosmos DB JS SQL SDK, which as the rest of the Cosmos DB SDKs (.NET, Java, Python) is used for Data Plane operations.

Creation of accounts is a Management operation.

- You can use [ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/quick-create-template)
- You can use the Azure CLI, which you already know
- You can use Powershell
- There are [Azure Management Libraries for JS](https://github.com/azure/azure-sdk-for-js#Management) but they don't seem to include Cosmos DB yet. There are [.NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/cosmos-db/Microsoft.Azure.Management.CosmosDB) versions though.